# php POST data and saving it

Tags: php, post

I get an error with my code to receive data from my android app. could someone please resolve my issue with this. I have included the error that I get when I POST the data.

```
<?php

    $filename = "uploads/";

    $filename = $filename."data".date.".txt";

    file_put_contents($filename, $_POST) ;


?>
```

Error log:

> [14-May-2012 09:49:32 UTC] PHP Warning: 
>   file_put_contents(uploads/datadate.txt) [function.file-put-contents]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/kiwigami/public_html/upload.php on line 27

Comment: try the full path for the file and make sure the permissions are correct.

Comment: what is date in this line 
    $filename = $filename."data".date.".txt";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have a `uploads` directory under `/home/kiwigami/public_html/`

Comment: +1, And make sure the uploads directory is writable by the web server user.